# my smoke simulation is barely visible in cycles

Tags: mesh, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I am trying to do some smoke simulation so I tried it my self everything is good for now , but when I tried to bake it the smoke is barely visible As you can see in the pictures my settings , I want to make the smoke kind of like dissolve to the floor which is I tried to follow the video here on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmBxaFgawLI&ab_channel=Polyfjord , how can I make the smoke visible and also dissolve like this ?
thanks in advance to everyone[image]

Comment: Polyfjord has video tutorials about smoke simulations, why not watch them? There he explains dissolving smoke and also how to setup a smoke material for the domain. Unfortunately you did not even provide a screenshot of the smoke material setup - which is what it makes appear in render. So how should we find out what is wrong? At first of all I would say, maybe you should increase the density in the smoke material? And for Polyfjord, instead of trying to guess what to do from the result, you should watch the tutorial on creating it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3JKDEyPj6g